# Remove "randomized" and "input" values from a procedural list

Tags: python, list, random, input, counter

I recently played the Werewolf game with some friends, in order to ease the Game Master work I wanted to create a simple Python program allowing fast roles randomization.

I'm not a professional nor someone with high Python skills, I just understand how algorithms work so I lack vocabulary to shape my ideas, but I managed to create a working code:

```
import random

Roles = ['a werewolf', 'the werewolf seer', 'the fool', 'the seer', 'the witch', 'the    hunter', 'the priest', 'cupidon', 'the little girl', 'the bodyguard']
List = []
Counter = 0
Players = int(input("How many player are there ? "))

while Counter < Players:

    print("Player", Counter + 1, end=", ")
    Name = (input("What is your name ? "))
    List.append(Name)
    Counter = Counter + 1

for i in range(Players):

    print(random.choice(List), ", You are", random.choice(Roles))
```

The problem is, roles and names are randomized, so I can't tell my program to exclude just listed values, therefore some names are duplicated as well as some roles.

I have 3 questions:

- How can I refer to input values from a list?
- How can I refer to randomized values from a list?
- How can I tell my program to remove just listed values (randomized or input) from the list in order to avoid duplicates?

Comment: I'm not totally clear what you're asking - you seem to have answered Q2 yourself. I would rename `List` to avoid confusing with the `list` type. To access it's items you can use `for player in List: print(player)`, I don't think you need to randomly select from it?

Comment: Do you want each player to have different roles perhaps (i.e. if player 1 is `the fool` then no other player can take that role?)

Comment: You're right, I will give"List" another name, it could be confusing.

Yes, you understood the idea, I want each player to get a random role, that's why it needs to be randomly selected, but don't worry, Ali Yazdanifar already gave me the missing lines of the code, it works great now :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think this is work for you :)

```
    import random

Roles = ['a werewolf', 'the werewolf seer', 'the fool', 'the seer', 'the witch', 'the    hunter', 'the priest', 'cupidon', 'the little girl', 'the bodyguard']
List = []
Counter = 0
Players = int(input("How many player are there ? "))

while Counter < Players:

    print("Player", Counter + 1, end=", ")
    Name = (input("What is your name ? "))
    List.append(Name)
    Counter = Counter + 1

for i in range(Players):
    rand_names = random.choice(List)
    rand_roles = random.choice(Roles)
    List.remove(rand_names)
    Roles.remove(rand_roles)
    print(rand_names, ", You are", rand_roles)
```

Comment: It works perfectly, thanks a lot for taking time to answer :D

I have another question if you don't mind : How can I add a percentage to get a role ? For instance if there is 8 players for 20 roles, and I would like some roles to have a higher chance to appear, what function/vocabulary do I need to use ?

Comment: You could use random.choices (https://docs.python.org/dev/library/random.html#random.choices) with k=1 and set weights to the probability of each role. The slightly tricky thing is you'd have to remove both the role and it's associated probability each time you select one.

Comment: Got it, thanks David, I'll try it as soon as possible !

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure this is what you want, I've assumed you want different roles per players. Also if this is the case there should be a check that Players is not more than the number of roles.

```
import random

Roles = ['a werewolf', 'the werewolf seer', 'the fool', 'the seer', 'the witch', 'the    hunter', 'the priest', 'cupidon', 'the little girl', 'the bodyguard']
PlayerNames = []
Counter = 0
Players = int(input("How many player are there ? "))

while Counter < Players:
    print("Player", Counter + 1, end=", ")
    Name = (input("What is your name ? "))
    PlayerNames.append(Name)
    Counter = Counter + 1

for player in PlayerNames:
    role = random.choice(Roles)
    Roles.remove(role)
    print(player, ", You are", random.choice(Roles))
```

Comment: Yeah you got the idea, but your code is misformulated, resulting in some roles duplicating themselves.
No worries, as you can see Ali Yazdanifar added some lines in my program, now it works perfectly :)

I like your idea, adding a check would make the code better so I think I will add one, thanks for your suggestion, and thanks for your help !